# how can I add a new column which counts the number of rows as serial number

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
record of
id  fare    commission  routecode   vehicle number  productcode date    time    driver  owner name
15  12345   123 4533    1   3344    2011-03-18  00:00:00    yasir   saleem
20  a   a   3433    1   2333    2011-03-25  00:00:00    yasir   saleem
36  11111   11111   3433    1   2333    2011-03-25  16:13:12    yasir   saleem
9   1233    123 3433    nk-234  2333    2011-03-24  00:00:00    siddiq  aslam
21  1200    120 4533    nk-234  7655    2011-03-24  00:00:00    siddiq  aslam
22  1200    133333  0987    nk-234  2333    2011-03-11  00:00:00    siddiq  aslam
23  10000   11  4533    nk-234  7655    2011-03-19  00:00:00    siddiq  aslam
25  122 12  0987    nk-234  2333    2011-03-11  00:00:00    siddiq  aslam
26  1000    100 3344    nk-234  7655    2011-03-11  00:00:00    siddiq  aslam
27  1000    100 3344    nk-234  2333    2011-03-10  00:00:00    siddiq  aslam
34  100 10  3344    nk-234  2333    2011-03-18  00:00:00    siddiq  aslam
35  100 10  3344    nk-234  2333    2011-03-02  00:00:00    siddiq  aslam
5   1000    100 1234    wq1233  3344    2011-03-10  22:30:00    waqas   sami
6   2222    22  1234    wq1233  3344    2011-03-17  22:30:00    waqas   sami
24  a   a   4533    PSS-1234    7655    2011-03-02  00:00:00    salman  salam
42633   145175
```

I want to add another column before id which counts the number of

rows. It should start from 1 and increment by 1 for each row.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you mean in a SELECT statement:

Say your select was

```
select * from tbl
```

It becomes

```
select @n := @n + 1 RowNumber, t.*
from (select @n:=0) initvars, tbl t
```

Notes:

1. `select @n:=0` is used to reset the global variable to 0
2. `@n := @n + 1` increases it by 1 for each row, starting from 1. This column is named "RowNumber"

Comment: if you have understood OP's question, can you explain it to me? I am really confused ^_^

Comment: @Starx : concentrate only on the last sentence `start from 1 and increment by 1 for each row.` This column holds just a sequential numbering of the records. At least that's how I read it

Answer (score 11):

Add a new column `mySerial` to the table `myTable` and increment each row by 1 (starting at '1'):

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD mySerial int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL;
SELECT @n:=0;
UPDATE myTable SET mySerial = @n := @n + 1;
```

Comment: How it is different to the accepted and upvoted answer? What does it adds?

Comment: @Yaroslav The accepted answer does only add the counter to a select. This one change the original table. I were not able to conclude from the accepted answer to this one with update.

Comment: SQL Error [1048] [23000]: Column 'mySerial' cannot be null

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to add a column to every row with the rowcount in it? It's not possible to do that automatically, but you can add a column and update it on every insert (`UPDATE table SET (rowcount = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE)`) but I wonder why you want to do that? It seems to me you want to workaround something and I think there must be a better solution than adding a rowcount column.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand your question completely, but to add a column infront of id run this query

```
ALTER TABLE `yourtablename` ADD `yournewfield` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL BEFORE `id`
```

Comment: exactly i select this from different tables and table dont have this column which add rows

Comment: I apologize @sadi, but what are you refering to as `this` and `this column` and I completely do not understand the part `column which add rows`

Comment: @starx new column which count number of rows or record
which i select
s.no
1
2
3

Comment: @sadi, do you mean create a column, which creates a column to hold SN

Comment: @starx exactly i want this in mysql

Comment: @sadi, use @Richard aka cyberkiwi's answer he has your solution. Just run his query in phpmyadmin to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into this blog post: http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/

Seems to have a solution for adding a row number to a query result, which might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assigning sequential numbers to rows

The following statement uses the ROW_NUMBER() function to assign a sequential number to each row from the products table:

[linkhere](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) try this: row_number

row_number() over(order by column_name)

example:
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
ORDER BY productName
) row_num,
productName,
msrp
FROM
products
ORDER BY
productName;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).