# SQL: Skip entries in an order without knowing total entry amount

Tags: mysql, sql

The title is a bit confusing, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 10
```

and then only take the ones after the 10th one (or none if there are less than or equal to 10 entries).

*EDIT* I guess another way to do this would be to order them by timestamp, descending, and then somehow limit to `0, (total-someNumber)`.

Comment: So you want to skip the first 10 entries?

Comment: @AdamJones Yes, for what is before the *EDIT*. I don't know why I couldn't think of the word skip :3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By specifying an OFFSET you can get the rows after a specified number.  You combine this with limit.
In MySQL you achieve this with `LIMIT [offset], limit`.

Example - get 10 records after the oldest 10 records:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 10, 10;  # Retrieve rows 11-20
```

Example - get 20 records after the newest 5 records:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 5, 20;  # Retrieve rows 6-25
```

If you want to get ALL rows after a certain number (eg. 10) then you pass an arbitrarily big number for the limit since it is required by the clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 10,18446744073709551615;  # Retrieve rows 11-BIGINT
```

Note: `18446744073709551615` is the maximum of an unsigned BIGINT and is provided as the solution within the MySQL documentation.

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: What I want is to be able to skip the first, say 10, entries, and then get all the rest.

Comment: See my extended answer. MySQL requires you to specify a maximum number of rows, but as the manual suggests use the largest number to return all rows after your offset

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351628/how-can-i-add-a-new-column-which-counts-the-number-of-rows-as-serial-number) and then just add a where clause that skips the first n (n=10 in this case) rows.

i.e. using the linked example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (select @n := @n + 1 RowNumber, t.* from (select @n:=0) initvars, tbl t)
WHERE
    RowNumber > 10
```