# MySQL: How can I select hourly values from a field and then substract all consecutive rows from the result?

Tags: mysql, sql

Note: Solution at the end of the question

I have **accumulated** energy data every 15min in my table. I need to query this data to get the energy spent every hour of the current day.
To do so, I need to select the value of every hour and substract it from the value of the previous one, as shown in the picture.

[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL0nq.jpg)

With the following code I've already selected the hourly data, as shown in the result below:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FechaHora, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')as Horas, FechaHora, Pan_kWh_im
FROM gaia_piloto1 T1
JOIN (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FechaHora, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AS Horas,     MAX(FechaHora) AS MaxFH
    FROM gaia_piloto1
    WHERE FechaHora BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
    GROUP BY Horas) T2
ON T1.FechaHora = T2.MaxFH
```

[Intermediate Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1EQv.jpg)

Now I need to add some more code to do the substraction of consecutive rows.
How can I do it?

Thank you in advance for all your help,

SOLUTION:
Thanks to the suggestion made in the comments, I came with this solution, maybe not optimal but suits my needs:

```
SELECT T4.Horas, T4.kWh_hr
FROM (
    SELECT T3.Horas, T3.FechaHora, T3.Pan_kWh_im, (T3.Pan_kWh_im - @lastValue) AS kWh_hr, @lastValue:=T3.Pan_kWh_im AS Calc
    FROM (SELECT @lastValue := 0 ) initvars,
          ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FechaHora, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')as Horas, FechaHora, Pan_kWh_im
                FROM gaia_piloto1 T1
                JOIN (  (SELECT FechaHora AS Horas, FechaHora AS MinFH
                            FROM gaia_piloto1
                            WHERE FechaHora <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 Day,'%Y-%m-%d 23:01:00')
                            ORDER BY Horas DESC
                            LIMIT 1)
                            UNION
                            (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FechaHora, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AS Horas, MIN(FechaHora) AS MinFH
                            FROM gaia_piloto1
                            WHERE FechaHora BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
                            GROUP BY Horas
                            ORDER BY Horas DESC)
                        ) T2
                ON T1.FechaHora = T2.MinFH
                ORDER BY FechaHora ) T3
    ) T4
WHERE Horas >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Please, post some sample of table extract: `SELECT * FROM gaia_piloto1 ORDER BY FechaHora DESC LIMIT 15`

Comment: First I would add a row number to the intermediate result table. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351628/how-can-i-add-a-new-column-which-counts-the-number-of-rows-as-serial-number

And once the row number is added then create a query against the intermediate results that subtracts the n-1 value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Subtracting value from previous row, group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196190/mysql-subtracting-value-from-previous-row-group-by)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers!
All of them helped me to get a solution to my needs, although perhaps not the best one, as I'm new to SQL.

I edited the post to reflect the solution I came with, should it help someone else in the future. It's an integration of few methods I found through your suggestions.

Regards