# Generate Column representing the row's index within the group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a case where I have a table, which describes measurements at a certain date. However, there are different types of measurements (which may have the same date). The table looks something like this:

```
Table: measurements

type_id     date        value
--------------------------------
1           2018-12-31  40
1           2019-01-01  42
1           2019-01-02  43
1           2019-01-04  44
2           2019-01-01  80
2           2019-01-02  79
2           2019-01-05  78
```

(Note that 1/2019-01-03 and 2/2019-01-03 and 2/2019-01-04 are omitted!)

The different types are not comparable with each other and thus need to be strictly separate from each other.
The problem is that I have to join this table against another table, whose order is not based on dates, but uses an offset/index approach (integer) based on a baseline date (from where counting starts)! Note that this index counts the **lines** and is not an offset in terms of "days since ...".

For the sake of this example here, let's assume it looks like this (simplified from real life):

```
Table: type_master

type_id         base_date
--------------------------
1               2019-01-01
2               2019-01-01
3               2018-12-22
...
```

That is why I would like to have the "lines index count within in each group". So the resultset of an SQL statement (which will be executed on a MySQL/MariaDB) should look something similar like this:

```
type_id      date      value   index_in_group
-------------------------------------------
1           2018-12-31  40     null (and not -1!)
1           2019-01-01  42     1
1           2019-01-02  43     2
1           2019-01-04  44     3  (and not 4!)
2           2019-01-01  80     1
2           2019-01-02  79     2
2           2019-01-05  78     3  (and not 5!)
```

(indexing shall happen using the ascending order by date - you may assume that those dates which are skipped are also skipped intentionally).

I already started playing around with the idea mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5351692/6350762

```sql
select @n := @n + 1 index, m.*
from (select @n:=0) initvars, measurements m
```

which gives me the index counting quite well - but it ignores the change of group and keeps on counting, even when the new group started.

You may also consider the following:

- If possible, all this should eventually end up in a view.
- Writing a MySQL procedure would be possible, but would result in side-effects which are unwanted - if that was the case, then I could also implement the necessary logic on the application server which is running on top of the database. However, having the logic in the database would be prefered due to reasons of data access.
- Good performance would be nice, but is not of paramount importance: the number of records on `measurements` is in the order of 40k; the number of records on `type_master` is at some dozens.
- The server is running on MariaDB 10.1.26. (**Updated later on based on a comment**)

Any ideas how I can achieve this with an acceptable SQL statement?

Comment: If you can use MySQL 8.0, this is exactly what the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function is intended for. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+ and in recent versions of MariaDB, you can do use window functions:

```
select m.*,
       (case when m.date >= tm.base_date 
             then row_number() over (partition by type_id,
                                                  m.date >= tm.base_date
                                     order by m.date
                                    )
        end) as index_in_group
from measurements m left join
     type_master tm
     on m.type_id = tm.type_id;
```

In older versions, you can use variables.  This is a little tricky; I think the logic is:

```
select m.*,
       (@rn := if(m.date < tm.base_date, NULL,
                  if(@t = m.type_id, @rn + 1,
                     if(@t := m.type_id, 1, 1)
                    )
                 )
       ) as index_in_group
from (select m.*, tm.base_date
      from measurements m left join
           type_master tm
           on m.type_id = tm.type_id
      order by m.type_id, m.date
     ) m cross join
     (select @t := -1, @rn := 0) params
```

Comment: sh*t; the server is running on MariaDB 10.1.26; `ROW_NUMBER()` got introduced with 10.2 (see also https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_number/ ). Is there an easy alternative? (I have updated the question accordingly) - Still voting "up", as this is already very helpful in general.

Comment: The second variant is exactly what I needed! Thanks a million!

Comment: For the sake of completeness: The `SELECT` statement (second variant above) cannot be stored in a view on MariaDB 10.1.26 due to `ErrorCode 1351: View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter`. 
Yet, I believe that this is the closes to what we can get, so still keeping the "answered" flag for this answer.